# Old cartoon or anime about three superheroes living in a space ship and doing jobs for a Greek god

Tags: story-identification, anime, animation

I vaguely remember this cartoon or anime about three superheroes living in a space ship and doing jobs for a Greek god.

It must have been early 80s or late 70s.  I think the god appeared on a screen to give them missions. Sometimes they would fly out of the spaceship on adventures, other-times they took the spaceship with them.  I think the spaceship was based in an extinct volcano.

I think other Greek gods had their own teams, because sometimes they interacted.  And they must have had a cute robot, too, because at the end of one episode, Zeus' face appeared in space to thank the team for completing that week's mission.  Only the robot saw this, and the rest of the team refused to believe it.  Why that was so unbelievable in context, I can't remember.

I could be totally wrong about the gods being Greek.  My girlfriend says that I have asked this question before, but I don't remember that either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many elements of this sound similar to [*Space Sentinels*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0239192/) (1977).  Three humans have been turned into superheroes and fight threats to Earth from their spaceship hidden in a volcano.  They have a robot sidekick and a computer that projects a head to give advice and instructions.

[image: Title card for Space Sentinels showing the 3 heroes, their robot sidekick and the projected head of their computer.]

Quoting from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Sentinels#Premise):

> **Three young Earth people** were selected many centuries ago and teleported to another planet, where they were given eternal youth and **superpowers**. They were trained and returned to Earth, where they are tasked with protecting the planet and its vicinity, similar to the Green Lantern Corps. Hercules and Mercury through superhuman feats became the basis for the mythological Roman deities of the same names. They are joined by Astrea, namesake of the Greek deity but with unrelated powers.
>
> Their base of operations and living quarters is **a spaceship hidden within the caldera of a dormant volcano**. They are supervised by Sentinel One, a member of a series of sentient supercomputers that command and coordinate Sentinel teams, although the race that gave the Sentinels their powers is ostensibly humanoid. For missions anywhere on Earth, **the team is launched through vertical tubes and fly to their destination through the use of rocket belts in their suits**, which seem to have intercontinental range as well as hypersonic capability (although Mercury can fly even faster). **For interplanetary and interstellar missions, Sentinel One transports them within the spacecraft**, which has faster-than-light capability.

Once difference is that it is the team that have names out of Greek/Roman myth; some god-like antagonists use names out of other mythologies like Anubis and Loki.  There is at least one episode where they do need to help another Sentinel team.

Comment: I wonder if they might have mixed some elements of Ulysse 31 in their recollection, specifically the part about Zeus' face appearing in space

Comment: Ulysses 31 belongs to my period of youth that remembers cartoons clearly, but Space Sentinels was from the tantalising dark age of snippets, fragments and false memories.  I don't think I was getting them mixed up, but I was just guessing about Greek mythology in Space Sentinels, because Greek is always the first choice of writers in need a pantheon to plunder.